# Is "The reason is so..." redundant?

Tags: grammar

I know one should never use *The reason is because,* but does the same apply to *The reason is so?*

It would make sense, because when someone asks you "Why (insert question here)?" , it's common to reply, "So that (reason here)."

I'm not certain about this though and have not found anything online.

Comment: Er, "I know one should never use *The reason is because*, . . ." -- You might want to double check that assumption. A good source would be a usage dictionary, such as *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage*. (Online grammar sources are, more often than not, of dubious quality.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends; although it's *not* correct when used in the way you've intuited here to "make sense".

It *is* acceptable when one is speaking *about* the reason (rather than stating it), although its more typical to use *such* in this case rather than *so*.

The easiest example is, i.e., "...and this is why the reason is so", but it can also be phrased in ways similar to phrases like "...but unfortunately, its speciousness means the reason is such that one cannot...".